# SQLAlchemy add_all() inserting not working

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have my Flask API endpoint that doesn't to be saving all the information from `for loop` The endpoint uploads multiple images. All is working fine, i.e the images are being uploaded however when it comes to inserting the names to the database, no record(file name/url) is being inserted.

Endpoint:

```
def upload_images(args):
    """Upload room images """
    image_id = None

    for file in request.files.getlist('image_name'):
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            image_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
            filename = image_id + '.png'
            file.save(os.path.join(current_app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))

            #Resize Images
            _image_resize(current_app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], image_id, 600, 'lg')
            _image_resize(current_app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], image_id, 150, 'sm')
    get_image = RoomImages(**args)
    get_image.image_name = url_for('uploaded_file', filename=filename, _external=True)
    db.session.add_all(get_image)
    db.session.flush()
    db.session.commit()
    return get_image
```

Model:

```
class RoomImages(db.Model):
    __tablename__='ep_roomimages'

    id = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, primary_key=True)
    image_name = sqla.Column(sqla.String(128), unique=True)
    room_id = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, sqla.ForeignKey(Room.id), index=True)

    room_img = sqla_orm.relationship('Room', back_populates='room_images')


    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Room Images {}>'. format(self.image_name)
```

Error I am getting is: `TypeError: 'RoomImages' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those looking at this for a solution, here is my final edit. The code needed some indenting of the functions for it to work well.

```
files = request.files.getlist('image_name')
    for file in files:
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            image_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
            filename = image_id + '.png'
            file.save(os.path.join(current_app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))

            # Resize Images
            _image_resize(current_app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], image_id, 600, 'lg')
            _image_resize(current_app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], image_id, 150, 'sm')

            get_image = RoomImages(**args)
            get_image.image_name = url_for('uploaded_file', filename=filename, _external=True)
            db.session.add(get_image)
            db.session.commit()

    return get_image
```

Comment: I believe the second line shouldn't have any indentation